# Flexbox not wrapping in Firefox and IE11

Tags: css, internet-explorer, firefox, flexbox

I have a flexbox grid on [my website](http://fotolienzo.com/) which is not displaying correctly in IE11 and Firefox.

```css
.section-home {
  float: left;
}
/*** Flex Grid ***/

.flex-grid {
  display: flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
}
.flex-grid .flex-item {
  display: flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  margin-top: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="section-home">
  <!-- PRODUCTS -->
  <div class="products-home flex-grid">
    <div class="flex-item">
      <div class="collection-item animated shown">
        <div class="collection-wrap">
          <div class="collection-image">
            <a href="{{ route('cuadrospersonalizados') }}">
              <img class="img-responsive" src="{{ FotImg::asset('img/fotolienzos.jpg') }}?dts={DPL_TS}" alt="Cuadros personalizados" title="Cuadros personalizados">
              <span class="description">
                        <p>Lienzo con tus fotos colocado sobre madera de pino</p>
                    </span>
              <div class="caption">
                <h2>Fotolienzos</h2>
              </div>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item">
      <div class="collection-item animated shown">
        <div class="collection-wrap">
          <div class="collection-image">
            <a href="{{ route('fotolienzosconreloj') }}">

              <img class="img-responsive" alt="Fotolienzos con Reloj" title="Fotolienzos con Reloj" src="{{ FotImg::asset('img/fotolienzos-con-reloj.jpg') }}?dts={DPL_TS}">

              <div class="label-new">
                <span class="new">novedad</span>
              </div>

              <span class="description">
                            <p>Lienzo personalizado con reloj colocado sobre bastidor de madera</p>
                        </span>

              <div class="caption">
                <h2>Fotolienzos con Reloj</h2>
              </div>

            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="flex-item">
      <div class="collection-item animated shown">
        <div class="collection-wrap">
          <div class="collection-image">
            <a href="{{ route('posterspersonalizados') }}">
              <img class="img-responsive" alt="Pósters personalizados" title="Pósters personalizados" src="{{ FotImg::asset('img/posters-personalizados.jpg') }}?dts={DPL_TS}">
              <span class="description">
                        <p>Pósters especialmente pensados para habitaciones juveniles e infantiles</p>
                    </span>
              <div class="caption">
                <h2>Pósters personalizados</h2>
              </div>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- PRODUCTS -->
</div>
```

The flex grid displays correctly in Chrome but in IE and Firefox the items stay on one line and do not wrap. Why is this?

Comment: I edited the main post

Comment: Did you add all the required vendor prefixes? It looks OK to me in FF but IE has a scrollbar.

Comment: yes but not working...in IE11, In Firefox you must resize the screen 1200px or less

Comment: @FunnyFrontend I've amended your code to allow us to reproduce the issue in your question. Please be aware that the issue needs to be reproducible in the question itself, linking to your site is not enough as if the issue gets fixed the question will be of little use to other users having the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that the container around `.flex-grid` (`.section-home`) is set to `float: left;` and has no `width` set. This means it will be set to `width: auto;` which, as it is a floated element, will mean that its content will govern how wide it is. In this case there appears to be a difference in how the browsers choose to calculate the width:

- Chrome limits `.section-home` to the width of its parent
- IE lets `.section-home` grow as much as it needs to accommodate  all children of `.flex-grid`

There are a couple of ways you could tackle this, however, the simplest will be to remove `float: left;` from `.section-home` as it appears it is not needed anyway.

```css
.section-home {
  /*float: left; Remove this*/
}
/*** Flex Grid ***/

.flex-grid {
  display: flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
}
.flex-grid .flex-item {
  display: flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  margin-top: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="section-home">
  <!-- PRODUCTS -->
  <div class="products-home flex-grid">
    <div class="flex-item">
      <div class="collection-item animated shown">
        <div class="collection-wrap">
          <div class="collection-image">
            <a href="{{ route('cuadrospersonalizados') }}">
              <img class="img-responsive" src="{{ FotImg::asset('img/fotolienzos.jpg') }}?dts={DPL_TS}" alt="Cuadros personalizados" title="Cuadros personalizados">
              <span class="description">
                        <p>Lienzo con tus fotos colocado sobre madera de pino</p>
                    </span>
              <div class="caption">
                <h2>Fotolienzos</h2>
              </div>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item">
      <div class="collection-item animated shown">
        <div class="collection-wrap">
          <div class="collection-image">
            <a href="{{ route('fotolienzosconreloj') }}">

              <img class="img-responsive" alt="Fotolienzos con Reloj" title="Fotolienzos con Reloj" src="{{ FotImg::asset('img/fotolienzos-con-reloj.jpg') }}?dts={DPL_TS}">

              <div class="label-new">
                <span class="new">novedad</span>
              </div>

              <span class="description">
                            <p>Lienzo personalizado con reloj colocado sobre bastidor de madera</p>
                        </span>

              <div class="caption">
                <h2>Fotolienzos con Reloj</h2>
              </div>

            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="flex-item">
      <div class="collection-item animated shown">
        <div class="collection-wrap">
          <div class="collection-image">
            <a href="{{ route('posterspersonalizados') }}">
              <img class="img-responsive" alt="Pósters personalizados" title="Pósters personalizados" src="{{ FotImg::asset('img/posters-personalizados.jpg') }}?dts={DPL_TS}">
              <span class="description">
                        <p>Pósters especialmente pensados para habitaciones juveniles e infantiles</p>
                    </span>
              <div class="caption">
                <h2>Pósters personalizados</h2>
              </div>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- PRODUCTS -->
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks!, perfect answer :D

Comment: @FunnyFrontend No problem, glad I could help.